# Python runtime error dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have made this code, I believe the problem is in Line 30 (32), I get the following error about the dictionary   **"RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"** I am at a loss, a google search and a look around stack overflow had some examples and similar issues but I cant seem to figure it out, thanks for your help.

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from bisect import insort

graph = defaultdict(list)
edges = []
with open("blu.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        graph[key].append(val)
        graph[val].append(key)
        edges.append((key, val))

k = 3
change = True
while change:
    change = False
    for edge in edges:
        inter = set(graph[edge[0]]).intersection(graph[edge[1]])
        if len(inter) < (k - 2):
            if edge[1] in graph[edge[0]]:
                graph[edge[0]].remove(edge[1])
                change = True
            if edge[0] in graph[edge[1]]:
                graph[edge[1]].remove(edge[0])
                change = True

g = dict((key, value) for key, value in graph.items() if value)
for key, v in g.items():
    for k, value in g.items():
        if key in value:
            g.pop(key, None)

for key, value in g.items():
    a = []
    insort(a, key)
    for v in value:
        insort(a, v)
    print (tuple(a))


# for x in graph:
# print (x, graph[x])


# def generate_edges(graph):
#     edges = []
#     for k in graph:
#         for neighbour in graph[k]:
#             edges.append((k, neighbour))
#     return edges


# print(generate_edges(graph))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate over and mutate a dictionary at the same time, see below:

```
for key, v in g.items():
    for k, value in g.items():
        if key in value:
            g.pop(key, None)    # You can't do this in a loop. What are you trying to accomplish in the end?
```

First of all, you're looping twice, for no particular reason. And then you're popping while iterating over `g`. Can you give us a sample input and output with more details?

Answer (score 0):

this line - g.pop(key, None)
You are editing the dictionary in a for loop which is forbidden
instead use something like
keys = g.keys()
values = g.values() 
then iterate through those instead